# How to find the data sent to create a new Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20

I am currently learning Solidity & Blockchain development. Came across an instance, where a new ERC20 Token contract was created from a front end App. While checking the Contract, I found a bunch of data was sent to the Contract Constructor to create it. How do I find what all data was sent?
While checking the Tx details, I could not find.

see this tx,
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x64f947e6f4e2fde4d2fa44d67eb1abbe0b95eba193e3370377246240432677a3

Input data is binary I guess. Is there a way to decode the it to find out what all info was sent to it to create the Contract?

Thanks